# How do I reference a class made up of classes from a Unity3D monobehaviour?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, subclass, nullreferenceexception

I have made a class to organize some data, and a class made up of several of those classes (Subclass?) so I can do something like...

```
classA.classB.value = 1;
```

However I can't figure out how to reference my classes. If anybody knows how I should go about it that would be great!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

class Gene {
    public string name;
    public float value;
    public float complexity;

    public Gene() {
        name = "";
        value = 0;
        complexity = 0;
    }

    public Gene(string Name, float Value, float Complexity) {
        name = Name;
        value = Value;
        complexity = Complexity;
    }
}

class Genome {
    public Gene agility;
    public Gene intelligence;
    public Gene strength;

    public Genome(){
        agility = new Gene();
        intelligence = new Gene();
        strength = new Gene();
    }

    public Genome(Gene Agility, Gene Intelligence, Gene Strength) {
        agility = Agility;
        intelligence = Intelligence;
        strength = Strength;
    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }
}

public class Life : MonoBehaviour {
    Genome genome;      //Warning Life.genome is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
    Quantity quantity;  //Warning Life.quantity is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

    void OnEnable() {
        genome = /*???*/;   //How do I add the reference?
        quantity = /*???*/; //How do I add the reference?

        genome.agility.name = "Agility"; //On Runtime: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        genome.agility.complexity = 100;

        genome.intelligence.name = "Intelligence";
        genome.intelligence.complexity = 1000;

        genome.strength.name = "Strength";
        genome.strength.complexity = 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `new` keyword to initialize both `genome` and `quantity`. You use the `new` keyword for initialization when the class you are trying to initialize does not derive from `MonoBehaviour`. Your `Genome` and `Quantity` classes does not derive from `MonoBehaviour` so the new keyword is the proper way to do initialize them.

```
Genome genome = null;
Quantity quantity = null;

void Start()
{
    //initialize
    genome = new Genome(new Gene("", 0, 0), new Gene("", 0, 0), new Gene("", 0, 0));
    quantity = new Quantity ();

    //Now you can use both references
    genome.agility.name = "Agility"; 
    genome.agility.complexity = 100;

    genome.intelligence.name = "Intelligence";
    genome.intelligence.complexity = 1000;

    genome.strength.name = "Strength";
    genome.strength.complexity = 100;


}
```

Now if your `Genome` and `Quantity` classes both derive from `MonoBehaviour`. You should never should the new keyword to  initialize them.

For example:

```
class Gene :MonoBehaviour{

}
```

You don't use the new keyword for that, you use `addComponent` or `Instantiate` GameObject the script is attached to. And you should never have a constructor in the class if it will derive from `MonoBehaviour`.

```
void Start()
{
  genome = gameObject.AddComponent<Gene>();
}
```

Comment: Note that `Genome` and `Quantity` aren't descendants of `AudioClip`. Consider some revision to avoid misleading the OP.

Comment: Making them actually a `new Genome()/Quantity()` and you are good to go ;)

Comment: @Serlite That is a typo I used to make it compile since I don't have his script on my side. I forgot to change them back to his Genome  and Quantity

Comment: `genome = new Genome();`

"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Agility' of 'Genome.Genome(Gene,Gene,Gene)'"

Comment: @Wafer Small (important) note - if you're using a default constructor in C#, make sure you define it in the class if you've already defined an overloaded constructor! The compiler doesn't generate a default one when an overloaded one is given, and hence won't find a definition for it. =P (Answer writer should probably make an edit to reflect that.)

Comment: You pass all the values in the constructor. Something like `new Genome(new Gene("Agility", 5, 100), new Gene("Intelligence", 5, 1000), new Gene("Strength", 5, 100))` where  5 is a random value I chose since you don't have something for that in your code.

Comment: @Serlite how would I do that? I believe that would solve the error I'm getting:

"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Agility' of 'Genome.Genome(Gene,Gene,Gene)'"

Comment: @Wafer look at my naswer. updated it. Still not done. By the way, your Quantity class in not in the question.

Comment: @Programmer I really have to do add `new Gene("", 0, 0)` for each empty slot in the class I need? I've removed a whole ton of Genes to make the question easier to answer but things are going to get pretty messy, I've got over 30 of them. Is there no way to reference Genome without having to manually add a blank entry for each Gene?

Comment: You would not add all those other entries afterwards.

Comment: @Wafer You can use an array or List to allow initialization through a loop, which will make it a lot less wordy (in code). Additionally, by defining a default constructor ([view Example 1 of this resource for an idea of what they look like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)), you can instantiate classes without any parameters.

Comment: All of those `genome.agility.name` lines would not be needed if you do it directly with the constructor.

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes it would eliminate the bottom section I was using to assign them. However for the sake of the question and scalability and readability, suppose this class had over Genes, to create the initial reference to the class that's 1000 of this: `new Gene("", 0, 0)` which is very unorganized and if I was using it to assign values would be very hard to modify later.

Comment: Well, having tons of data is always a problem. You might be best of using some external storage like json or xml and have a function that reads that file and creates all your stuff.

Comment: @GunnarB. So there is no way for me to write `genome = new Genome();` and assign them later?

Comment: @Wafer If you don't want to be doing `new Gene("", 0, 0)`, remove that constructor and now you can just do ` genome = new Genome()`

Comment: There is. Just add a `public Genome(){}` to your Genome.cs like @Serlite mentioned.

Comment: Just modified his question with that `public Genome(){`

Comment: That's just the principle of overloading which works for functions and constructors and means that a class has multiple versions of a certain function/constructor with different parameter lists.

Comment: Actually one thing that must be changed (I think) is that Genome.cs has to implement `IEnumerator`.

Comment: @GunnarB I dislike when people jump to unity without learning C#, Java or C++. You get questions like these.  We spent 30 minutes talking about constructor error....

Comment: By adding `public Genome(){ }` I am able to set the reference but then I still get the NullReferenceException I was getting before when I try to assign `genome.agility.name = "Agility"`

And if I remove the constructors I get a bunch of warnings on each gene "Field 'genome.agility' is never assigned to" AND still get the NullReferenceException

Comment: I think what @Serlite is getting at is what I need to do, I'm just trying to figure out how to convert what I have to the example on msdn

Comment: @Wafer Dude please lean basic C# class. Watch class tutorials and you shouldn't have these problems. That's because `agility`,`intelligence` and `strength` are not initialized when you call `Genome()` instead of the other overload. You must initialize three of them with `genome.agility = new Gene("name", 0, 0);`, `genome.intelligence= new Gene("name", 0, 0);` , and `genome.strength= new Gene("name", 0, 0);,` after using `genome = new Genome();`

Comment: @Wafer You wont lean C# from MSDN. It is hard to understand on MSDN. Find a good tut on youtube. This is not unity question. This is a very basic c# question. Watch the videos for a week and you will be fine. The more I/WE explain, the more you ask and they all basic stuff you should know before going into unity.

Comment: I edited the question so that `Gene` now has a parameterless constructor and the parameterless constructor of `Genome` just calls that for the three genes it has. That way `new Genome()` will initialize all three genes with default values. (That should be visible soon.)

Comment: @GunnarB. Thank you this is exactly what I needed. However for the sake of anyone reading this, the `public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
  return (IEnumerator)this;
 }` section of code returns a 'cannot cast from source type to destination type.' error.

Comment: This should be solved by implementing `IEnumerator` I think. (GetEnumerator is a function of the interface.)

Comment: @GunnarB. How would I do that? IEnumerator was working before making the changes you suggested in your edit.

Comment: Really? That surprises me actually since GetEnumerator is part of IEnumerable. Have a look on how to make a class enumerable, there are plenty of instructions for that if you really need to do that.

Comment: Yea my guess is since it's assigning a `new Gene()` it isn't counting them? Problem was adding `public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
  return this;
 }` at the bottom was what I found to mak a class enumerable.

Comment: @Wafer You need to start accepting answers. You were shown how to get a reference and your `genome` null exception is gone. The problem you have now is totally different from your original problem. Cheers!

Comment: Right! Sorry, I do not use this very often. I also don't believe I had the privilege of accepting answers right from making an account, and was not aware I had earned it.

Comment: @Wafer You have privilege to accept answer once you register. You just won't have one to up-vote until you reach 16 points. You also need to accept other answers from your old questions. It makes people answer your question more.